# Problem understanding output of C program

Tags: c

I have the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i =257;
int *iptr =&i;
printf("%d%d",*((char*)iptr),*((char*)iptr+1));
return 0; 
}
```

The output is:

```
1 1
```

I am not able to understand why the second value is `1`.
Please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 257 in binary is `00000001 00000001`: So both the first and the second bytes representing it are set to 1.

`(char*)iptr` is the `char` (thus 1 byte) pointed by `iptr`, and `(char*)iptr+1` is the next byte.

Comment: Keep in mind this is only true if your integer is two bytes or if you are little-endian. Otherwise it may be stored as `0x00,0x00,0x01,0x01` and you would get `0 0` as the output.

Answer (score 6):

Same reason the first value is coming out 1. You're accessing a single byte at a time from an int. Since 257 is `0x0101`, the two least significant bytes each contain the value 1.

Probably your int is 4 bytes long and stored little-endian, although I suppose it could be 2 bytes long with either endian-ness.

Answer (score 2):

257 hexadecimally as 4 bytes = 0x00000101, which on Intel machines is stored in memory
as 01 01 00 00. iptr points to the first 01, and iptr+1 to the second.